# Get elements of one array from another in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array of only email of users:

```
const onlyEmailArray = ['test@gmail.com', 'test2@gmail.com']
```

And an array of full details:

```
const fullDetailsArray = [
  { email: 'test@gmail.com', phone: '337654987' },
  { email: 'test2@gmail.com', phone: '227654987' }
]
```

I want to search `fullDetailsArray` for emails that appear in `onlyEmailArray`
and get the the full object.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const filtered = fullDetailsArray.filter(d => onlyEmails.includes(d.email))`

Answer (score 1):

```js
const onlyEmailArray = ['test@gmail.com', 'test2@gmail.com'];
const fullDetailsArray = [
  { email: 'test@gmail.com', phone: '337654987' },
  { email: 'test2@gmail.com', phone: '227654987' }
];

// add onlyEmailArray elements to a Set
const emailSet = new Set(onlyEmailArray);

// filter fullDetailsArray
const filteredList = fullDetailsArray.filter(({ email }) => emailSet.has(email));

console.log(filteredList);
```

Answer (score 1):

To find the email at index `n` in onlyEmailArray:

```
fullDetailsArray.find((full) => full.email === onlyEmailArray[n] )
```

which will return the corresponding object in `fullDetalsArray`.

```js
const onlyEmailArray = ['test@gmail.com', 'test2@gmail.com'];
const fullDetailsArray = [
  { email: 'test@gmail.com', phone: '337654987' },
  { email: 'test2@gmail.com', phone: '227654987' }
];

n = 0;
res = fullDetailsArray.find((full)=> full.email === onlyEmailArray[n]  )

console.log(res);
```